# Convert string to uuid in vanilla JavaScript without external dependencies

Tags: javascript

I'm in a situation where I need to run some javascript in a place where I cannot use external packages.

Ideally the function should take a string as parameter and return a string in the format of a uuid (not random), based on the string parameter of course.

I've been searching all over the internet but except a few npm packages I could not find a simple and short function for doing so, since most of the functions are just random uuidv4 functions.

Since I need this to run some js in an external application, it is important that no external dependencies are used, and also the shorter the better.

Use case:

I have an entity without an id (uuid) field.
It does have 2 other ids however.
Before I persist it I want to generate an id in the format of a uuid based on a concatenated string of `${fooId}-${barId}` so I will be able to get the resource by this id from the API.

If I did not have the limitation of not being able to use external dependencies / npm packages and scripts, I would have used the uuid package and the uuidv5. Sadly I do not have this possibility, so I thought it would be possible to to this in a single vanilla js function.

If I was not clear before I need to figure out what to put here

```
const stringToUuid = (str) => {
  // return string formatted as a uuid, based on the str parameter
}
```

Comment: Search for *creating a hash from a string*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Comment: You shouldn't be generating UUIDs based on strings - that's a pretty sure way to make them something that's definitely not Universally Unique Identifiers.

Comment: @DCR no, why would you think that?

Comment: @titus I guess I'd need to generate a md5 / sha1 hash or something, and then use add the dashes afterwards. Seems like a lot of work in vanilla js, since I cannot use any dependencies. Had hoped it would be possible to do with less code.

Comment: @AKX I need this since I do not have a uuid as my id field, but will need to generate it from 2 other fields on that entity before I persist it. So the uniqueness would be the combination of those 2 values in a concatenated string. But I'd like it represented as a uuid similar to the uuidv5 from the uuid npm package which I could have used if I had the possibility of importing an external dependency, which I don't

Comment: You can write your own hashing method or find a simple one online. Hashing is just a consistent way of reducing something's size, the main requirement is to get the same result for the same thing, how you do that is up to you.

Comment: Then I'm left with turning that simple hash into the format of a uuid. I don't really feel like this is helping.

Comment: That is the easy part, it can be as simple as `"1234567890".match(/.{2}/g).join("-")`

Comment: Hmm not sure what to say. The hint's your giving me is not helping me that much. I have once found a function somewhere on the internet that took a string and did output a nice uuid-formatted string based on the str parameter. It was less than 10 lines of code and did not have any external dependencies. I couldn't find it again, which is why I created this question in hopes that someone would know how to make such a short  function. Now that I look into 32bit hashing and then some regex magic after, this task seems overly complicated.

Comment: Is the combination of `fooId` and `barId` unique? If that's the case you could roll over it replacing the characters of a uuid mask. That should be unique too, right?

Comment: @vicpermir yes `${fooId}-${barId}` would be a unique combination. But I need them as a single string in the form of a uuid. I don't understand what you mean by "roll over it replacing the characters of a uuid mask"

Comment: I have answered with what I meant but it's a pretty dumb solution so... maybe wait for other answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the combination of `fooId` and `barId` is unique you could iterate over them and fill some `UUID` mask.

```js
const stringToUuid = (str) => {
  str = str.replace('-', '');
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[x]/g, function(c, p) {
    return str[p % str.length];
  });
}

var input  = "813538-359512";
var output = stringToUuid(input);

console.log('Input: ' + input);
console.log('Output: ' + output);
```

The output should be a valid `UUID` string.

Caveats about `fooId` and `barId`:

- Both must contain only hexadecimal characters (I'm guessing they are numbers?)
- The length of both combined must be below 32 characters, otherwise the combination is longer than the characters replaced in the `UUID` mask and you could run into duplicates

It's a really simplistic way to solve your problem to be honest, I'm not sure of the implications or how robust it is.

If you want to combine two `UUID` to generate a third one you could operate on each character in pairs. In this case, it seems the most used operation is a bitwise `XOR` so that's what I'll do in this example:

```js
const stringToUuid = (uuid1, uuid2) => {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[x]/g, function(c, p) {
    var c1 = uuid1.charAt(p);
    var c2 = uuid2.charAt(p);
    return (parseInt(c1, 16) ^ parseInt(c2, 16)).toString(16).charAt(0);
  });
}

// Both must be valid UUID
var uuid1 = 'e7d24026-3081-4789-a6bd-34d8b69365ac';
var uuid2 = '6556c838-df63-461a-a415-852aa464f344';
var output = stringToUuid(uuid1, uuid2);

console.log('Uuid1: ' + uuid1);
console.log('Uuid2: ' + uuid2);
console.log('Output: ' + output);
```

The result should still be a valid `UUID`, but I guess you lose on uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ideally I hope for a solution that would work with any string as a parameter.

In this case both fooId and bazId are actually uuids, so this will not quite work, unless of course I remove the dashes from them, which I could of course just do.

I'll leave this question open a few days to see if I get more answers.

Comment: I think in line 2 it should be changed to `str = str.replace(/-/g, '');` - at least to work for uuids in the input variable

Comment: I have updated my answer, I didn't understand that you wanted to merge two `UUID` into a third one (just two numerical `IDs`). Quite a weird requirement honestly, phew :P

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why people say it's such a weird requirement, since I just need a unique id in a field before I persist it, since I want to be able to get the resource by that id instead of having to specify 2 ids, fooId and barId. Why is that such a weird requirement? Generating a string with the format of a uuid from a random string is not THAT unheard of is it? :D

Comment: Weird in the sense that usually you generate a random UUID and never operate on it. But you are right, that's what you need and it should be doable :P

Comment: how would you decode this back to strings?